# Match and store based on two columns in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a project that requires me to match two data frames based on two separate columns, X and Y.

e.g.

df1 =

```
|  X  |  Y  | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
| 2.0 | 1.5 | 25  |
| 1.0 | 0.5 | 29  |
| 1.5 | 0.5 | 21  |
| 2.0 | 2.0 | 32  |
| 0.0 | 1.5 | 19  |
```

df2 =

```
|  X  |  Y  | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
| 0.0 | 0.0 | []  |
| 0.0 | 0.5 | []  |
| 0.0 | 1.0 | []  |
| 0.0 | 1.5 | []  |
| 0.0 | 2.0 | []  |
| 0.5 | 0.0 | []  |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | []  |
| 0.5 | 1.0 | []  |
| 0.5 | 1.5 | []  |
| 0.5 | 2.0 | []  |
| 1.0 | 0.0 | []  |
| 1.0 | 0.5 | []  |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | []  |
| 1.0 | 1.5 | []  |
| 1.0 | 2.0 | []  |
| 1.5 | 0.0 | []  |
| 1.5 | 0.5 | []  |
| 1.5 | 1.0 | []  |
| 1.5 | 1.5 | []  |
| 1.5 | 2.0 | []  |
| 2.0 | 0.0 | []  |
| 2.0 | 0.5 | []  |
| 2.0 | 1.0 | []  |
| 2.0 | 1.5 | []  |
| 2.0 | 2.0 | []  |
```

The goal is to sort through df1, find the row with its matching coordinates in df2, and then store the AGE value from df1 in the AGE list in df2. The expected output would be:

df2 =

```
|  X  |  Y  | AGE |
|:--- |:---:|----:|
| 0.0 | 0.0 | []  |
| 0.0 | 0.5 | []  |
| 0.0 | 1.0 | []  |
| 0.0 | 1.5 |[19] |
| 0.0 | 2.0 | []  |
| 0.5 | 0.0 | []  |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | []  |
| 0.5 | 1.0 | []  |
| 0.5 | 1.5 | []  |
| 0.5 | 2.0 | []  |
| 1.0 | 0.0 | []  |
| 1.0 | 0.5 |[29] |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | []  |
| 1.0 | 1.5 | []  |
| 1.0 | 2.0 | []  |
| 1.5 | 0.0 | []  |
| 1.5 | 0.5 |[21] |
| 1.5 | 1.0 | []  |
| 1.5 | 1.5 | []  |
| 1.5 | 2.0 | []  |
| 2.0 | 0.0 | []  |
| 2.0 | 0.5 | []  |
| 2.0 | 1.0 | []  |
| 2.0 | 1.5 |[25] |
| 2.0 | 2.0 |[32] |
```

The code I have so far is:

```
for n in df1:
    if df1["X"].values[n] == df2["X"].values[n]:
        for m in df1:
            if df1["Y"].values[m]) == df2["Y"].values[m]:
                df2['AGE'].push(df1['AGE'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store age in lists:

```
df2 = df2[['X','Y']].merge(df1, on=['X','Y'], how='left')
df2['AGE'] = df2.apply(lambda row: [row['AGE']] if not pd.isnull(row['AGE']) else [], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `merge` operation that can be solved by not considering the `Age` column from df2, and merging **left** on `['X','Y']`:

```
df2 = df2[['X','Y']].merge(df1,on=['X','Y'],how='left')
```

Comment: I've tried this, however the lists in the AGE column in df2 still appear blank.

Comment: @PurpleSky I am not Celius Stingher, but this returns a new dataframe (as opposed to modifying `df2`) so you need to store the result, e.g. as `df2 = df2[['X', 'Y']].merge(df1, on=['X', 'Y'], how='left')`.

Comment: Thanks, edited the answer to account for this